Find all square roots of this matrix using some practical method

Find all matrices $A$ such that $$A=\displaystyle{\sqrt{\pmatrix{1 & 3 & -3 \\ 0 & 4 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 & 9}}}
$$
This is a UC Berkeley qualifying exam question.

Now I know one method to solve this.
Let $$A=\pmatrix{a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i}
$$
Now on squaring we'll get $9$ equations and can determine all variables.

I would like to know that whether there is any practical approach for this question. My method is impractical and can be used only in theory.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

A better ansatz might be to guess $$A = \pmatrix{a & b & c \ 0 & d & e \ 0 & 0 & f}$$ (the resulting equations are quite practical)

@BrianMoehring why did you assume a triangular matrix?? Is the square root of a triangular Matrix, triangular too?

Note that $1,4,9$ are the eigenvalues of your matrix, so $1,2,3$ is a good guess for the diagonals of an upper-triangular square root.

It could be.  There's one part of your question and comment that concerns me, though.  What do you mean by the square root?

Right, it should be "a square root."

I corrected it${}$

So if you start with $d,g,h=0$ and $a=1,e=2,i=3,$ you quickly can solve $b=1.$

@ThomasAndrews umm yeah I get it...the determinant has to be $6$ ...but is there any general way??

So the text of the question also reads "Find the matrix $A$ [...]"?  Again, my concern is reflected in your comment.  If we're looking for a square root and a matrix $A$, then we can improve your ansatz to only look at upper triangular matrices.  If you're trying to find something like all the square roots, then this is a different question.

@BrianMoehring i edited my question

Well, the determinant has to be $\pm6.$ But even stronger, the eigenvalues have to be $\pm1,\pm2,\pm3.$ In general, there is some diagonalizing matrix $B$ for your matrix $A$ so that $D=BAB^{-1}$ is diagonal with entries $1,4,9$ and you can easily compute $\sqrt D,$ and then one value of $\sqrt A$ is $B^{-1}\sqrt{D}B.$ Finding $B$ might be tricky.

Here's an approach which is lengthy and tedious but entirely formulaic, and no individual step is hard.
The eigenvalues of the matrix you seek are $\{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3\}$. So the characteristic polynomial is $(x \pm 1)(x \pm 2)(x \pm 3)$, which you can expand to eight possibilities.
By Cayley-Hamilton, $A$ satisfies its characteristic equation. Let's take one particular example, where the eigenvalues are $1,2,3$; then the characteristic equation is $-6I + 11A - 6A^2+A.A^2 = 0$. We already know $A^2$, so substitute that in, and we have a linear system of equations which we can easily solve for $A$ using e.g. Gaussian elimination (which in fact turns out to be extremely simple to do by hand in all the cases, the equations are quite nice).
Do this eight times and you have your answers. (Four of them will be the negation of the other four, but it's past 1am for me so it's not clear to me whether you can tell up front which four those will be, to skip the work.)
(I suspect you do also have to prove that your answers are square roots of $A$, by the way, because solutions to the characteristic equation define a matrix only up to similarity.)

If a solution $A$ has eigenvalues $x,y,z$, then $-A$ will be the solution with eigenvalues $-x,-y,-z$. So one way to skip half the work is to consider the cases with eigenvalues $1,2,3$, eigenvalues $1,2,-3$, eigenvalues $1,-2,3$, and eigenvalues $1,-2,-3$: the ones with an eigenvalue of $1$. The other four solutions, with an eigenvalue of $-1$, will be the negatives of these.

Also, to simplify the Gaussian elimination, we can look at what the characteristic equation tells us: replacing $A^2$ by $B$, in $-6I + 11A - 6A^2 + A^3 = 0$, we get $(B + 11I)A = 6I + 6B$. We can set this up as a $3 \times 6$ row reduction - essentially, solving $3$ systems of $3$ equations for the $3$ columns of $A$. Take your $3 \times 6$ matrix to be the matrix with $B+11I$ on the left and $6I+6B$ on the right, and row-reduce to get $I$ on the left; then $A$ will be on the right.

There are two parts to this exercise. The first one is showing that all solutions are upper triangular; the second is actually computing them.
I will not deal with the first, but once you have completed it, the second one is easy: by looking at the equations corresponding to equating the diagonal entries of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c\\
0 & d & e\\
0 & 0 & f
\end{bmatrix}^2 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 & -3\\ 0 & 4 & 5\\ 0 & 0 & 9\end{bmatrix}
$$
you get $a^2 = 1$, $d^2=4$, $f^2=9$; each of them has two solutions, so there are overall 8 possible choices. We shall see that each of them can be completed uniquely to one solution. It remains to determine $b,c,e$. You can get $b$ by comparing the $(1,2)$ entry of both sides of the equation:
$$
ab+bd = 3 \implies b = \frac{3}{a+d}.
$$
Similarly (equating the $(2,3)$ entries) you get $e = \frac{4}{d+f}$, and then knowing $b$ and $e$ you can compute $c = \frac{-3-be}{a+f}$.
This method to compute functions of a triangular matrix is known as Parlett recursion; it works whenever all the eigenvalues are simple.

Let $B$ be the matrix under the radical,
$$
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & -3 \\ 0 & 4 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 & 9
\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$
This answer solves the following problem:

Find all $3\times 3$ matrices $A$ so that:$$A^2 =B\ .$$


Short solution: The matrix $A_0=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 1 & -1 \\ & 2 & 1\\& & 3\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is one solution, found by searching it in upper triangular form. Let $D$ be diagonal with entries $1,2,3$, so the Jordan decomposition of $A_0$ is of the shape $A_0=SDT$, with $ST=I$.
Let $A$ be any solution of $A^2=B$. Associate $X=TAS$. Then $X^2 =TA^2S=TBS=TA_0^2S=(TA_0S)^2=D^2$. So $X^2-k^2I$ has rank two for $k^2\in\{1^2,2^2,3^2\}$, implying that the eigenvalues of $X$ are $\pm_k k$ (thus diufferent) with $k=1,2,3$, and independent choices of signs. Write $X=U\Lambda V$, Jordan decomposition, $UV=I$, $\Lambda$ diagonal. Then $U$ commutes with $D^2$,
$$
D^2U=X^2U=(U\Lambda V)^2U=U\Lambda^2VU=U\Lambda^2=UD^2\ ,$$
so $U$ is diagonal, $X=U\Lambda V=\Lambda UV=\Lambda$ is diagonal with entries $\pm_k\cdot k$, and finally
$\displaystyle
A=SXT=S\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\pm_1\cdot 1 & & \\ & \pm _2\cdot 2 & \\& & \pm_3\cdot 3\end{smallmatrix}\right]T$.
It remains to find the base change that diagonalizes the special solution $A_0$, all other solution become diagonal w.r.t. the same base change, a structural property.
$\square$

Expanded solution: (Same solution with details filled in.)
We are searching for one solution $A_0$ first. Because of the shape of $B$ it is natural to search it in the shape
$$
A_0=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & y \\ 0 & 2 & z \\ 0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}\ ,
$$
with unknowns $x,y,z$. The relation $A_0^2=B$ leads then to $3x=3$, $5z=5$, $xz+4y=-3$. We have the solution $x=z=1$, $y=-1$, and we set
$$
A_0=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$
We then find  column vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3\ne 0$ (with three components each), so that $A_0v_1=1\cdot v_1$, $A_0v_2=2\cdot v_2$, $A_0v_3=3\cdot v_3$, and build the matrix $S=[v_1,v_2,v_3]$ with these vectors as columns in the mentioned order.
(Build the matrices $A-I$, $A-2I$, $A-3I$ in between.)
The matrix multiplication can be done as "block matrix multiplication", so
$A_0S=A_0[v_1,v_2,v_3]=[A_0v_1,A_0v_2,A_0v_3]=[1\cdot v_1,2\cdot v_2,3\cdot v_3]$,
so using now suitable numbers...
$$
\begin{aligned}
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}}_{A_0}
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}}_{S}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}}_{S}
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}}_{D}\text{ i.e.}
\\
A_0S &=SD\ ,\\
A_0 &=SDT\ ,\qquad\text{ with }
T=S^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\ ,
\\
TA_0S &= D\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Let us come back to our equation, $A^2=B$. It is equivalent to $TA^2S=TBS$.
Note that $TA^2S=TAAS=TAS\;TAS=(TAS)^2$, and i will denote by $X$ the matrix
$$
X=TAS\ .
$$
Note that
$$ TBS=TA_0^2S=TA_0S\; TA_0S=DD=D^2\ ,$$
the diagonal matrix with entries $1^2, 2^2, 3^2$. So instead of solving $A^2=B$ we equivalently solve $X^2=D^2$.

As also mentioned in the comments, we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(X-I)(X+I) &= X^2 -1^2\;I=D^2-1^2\;I\ ,&&\text{ a matrix of rank two,}\\
(X-2I)(X+2I) &= X^2 -2^2\;I=D^2-2^2\;I\ ,&&\text{ a matrix of rank two,}\\
(X-3I)(X+3I) &= X^2 -3^2\;I=D^2-3^2\;I\ ,&&\text{ a matrix of rank two.}
\end{aligned}
$$
This implies that

among $\pm 1$ there is one eigenvalue of $X$,
among $\pm 2$ there is one eigenvalue of $X$,
among $\pm 3$ there is one eigenvalue of $X$.

We have three different eigenvalues, so $X=U\Lambda V$ with matrices $U,V$ inverse to each other, and $\Lambda$ diagonal, with diagonal entries in order, $\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3$ (eight choices). Then:
$$
D^2 = X^2 = (U\Lambda V)^2=U\Lambda^2 V= UD^2V\ ,
$$
so $D^2U=UD^2VU=UD^2$, so $U$ and $D^2$ commute. Multiplying with $D^2$ from the one or the other side induces operations of multiplying either row on the one side, or columns on the other side with respectively $1^2$, $2^2$, $3^2$. So the off-diagonal entries of $U$ vanish, so $U$ is diagonal, thus commutes with $\Lambda$, so
$$X=U\Lambda V=\Lambda UV=\Lambda\ .
$$
We went all the time in one direction, obtained for $X$ exactly eight choices. They obviously verify the relation $X^2=D^2$. Then it is enough to trace them back to $A$. It is an annoying step now to "find all matrices", if finding means computing the entries.

Using computer support (sage), here they are:
A0 = matrix(3, 3, [1, 1, -1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3])
B  = A0^2
S  = matrix(3, 3, [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
T  = S^-1

signs = [+1, -1]
for s1, s2, s3 in cartesian_product([signs, signs, signs]):
    X = diagonal_matrix([s1*1, s2*2, s3*3])
    A = S*X*T
    print(f"A_{{ {s1}, {s2}, {s3} }} &=\n{latex(A)}\\ ,\\\\")

And the print results are now inserted (copy+pasted) into an aligned block in mathjax:
$$
\tiny
\begin{aligned}
A_{ 1, 1, 1 } &=
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{array}\right)\ ,\\
A_{ 1, 1, -1 } &=
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & -5 \\
0 & 0 & -3
\end{array}\right)\ ,\\
A_{ 1, -1, 1 } &=
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & -3 & 3 \\
0 & -2 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{array}\right)\ ,\\
A_{ 1, -1, -1 } &=
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & -3 & 3 \\
0 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -3
\end{array}\right)\ ,\\
A_{ -1, 1, 1 } &=
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
-1 & 3 & -3 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{array}\right)\ ,\\
A_{ -1, 1, -1 } &=
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
-1 & 3 & -3 \\
0 & 2 & -5 \\
0 & 0 & -3
\end{array}\right)\ ,\\
A_{ -1, -1, 1 } &=
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
-1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & -2 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{array}\right)\ ,\\
A_{ -1, -1, -1 } &=
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
-1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -3
\end{array}\right)\ ,\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Note: My initial answer got a lot of downvotes. So i just removed its offensive part, not with a regret. Offensive in the sense that if i was in this situation some $30$ years ago in an oral exam, i would have started a quarrel with the examiner about the notation $\sqrt B$, more exactly on the function $\sqrt{\ \cdot\ }$ used in the question. And this because in an exam the examiner and the student are on the same footing in view of mathematics. It is the duty of the examiner to state a clear (university standard) and well defined (mathematical standard) question. The latter is hurt. The square root function is a function. Since the statement saids "Find all matrices $A$ such that $A$ is equal to $\sqrt B$, the  object $\sqrt B$ is a matrix. So the square root is not a multivalued function, but a well defined function from some part of the (undelying set of the) ring of $3\times 3$ matrices with entries in some ring, maybe $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, with values in the set of all matrices of the same shape over the same ring. So there is at most one answer. As seen above, there are eight candidates for this square root function. I am angry, because all the time i had to fight against this exam situation, when an unclear, moreover an intentionally unclear question came to the student, to me, and i had to "do my best" and guess the intention. For those who are interested in the effects of such a situation, i would post a link, a far but related situation:
The SAT question everyone got wrong
Exams in especially two countries, USA and India, have still this accepted touch of unclear questions where only one guess direction makes in the given mathematical situation some sense, and part of the exam is to make the right guess.

(This answer is extremely long and the first fifth of it has no mathematical content, instead being entirely a rant about how the question is sloppily worded. I'd probably upvote it if it were fewer than several pages long!)

@PatrickStevens Before some lines will be removed, please give a short answer to the question "what is $\sqrt {D^2}$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with entries $1,2,3$?". To have something to compare with, ethically, mathematically, didactically, and in order to have an exact problem at the base of the question, consider: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUHkTs-Ipfg&ab_channel=Veritasium (The SAT question everyone got wrong) Sometimes, writing an answer that covers the undefined parts of the question in all of its range is harder than the intention. This must become an issue.

This is basic exam technique. If you saw the question "Find $\sqrt{A}$ for this particular matrix $A$" in an exam, there's only one possible score-maximising way I can imagine interpreting it: "Find all $B$ such that $B^2 = A$". A correct answer to that question will presumably give you all the available marks. If particularly worried, a sentence at the top "as far as I know, $\sqrt{A}$ for matrices is not defined, so I have answered assuming it means ".

@PatrickStevens There was one clear question on my side. (This side represents the many frustrated students, that have a short question with not really well defined objects. This was not hidden in the answer.) Here we are not in an exam. Recall it: "What is the square root notation (or function) when applied on a matrix?" The question i saw was the following one: "Find all $A$ such $A=\sqrt B$." And now my question, exactly because of this twist: What kind of object is $$\sqrt B\ ?$$I am not asking how to give some sense to the problem. We are here on the side of mathematics.

By the way, this is the only answer that finds all the solutions of the equation $X^2=B$. I will shorten the story.

The question didn't ask for all the solutions, of course. It asks for a "practical approach". It's also, like, explicitly in an exam: the question's second sentence is "This is a UC Berkeley qualifying exam question".

@PatrickStevens You continuously ignore the questions i am writing, still not get the point. Just for the basic understanding: [Find all matrices $A$ so that $A=$something] implies that this "something" is a matrix, in case it is a horse or an alien we have no solution in UC Berkley. So there is at most one solution. The "question" is also not a question. We have an imperative or something like that, not my native language. OP implicitly asks then for a way to solve the equation $X^2=B$. All the time i have something with the statement. It is not well defined.

All I'm saying is that if you answered "this question is not well-defined" in the exam, you'd get no marks, whereas if you answered the question they obviously intended to ask then you'd get the marks!
